# Merging two branch in Bitbucket

Tags: git, eclipse, merge, bitbucket

I am new to Bitbucket and Git. Please help to in merging two branches using Eclipse.

Following is the scenario:

```
There was one branch - A 
New branch was created from A for Tech Upgrade - B 
New Branch was created from A for New Features - C 
New Branch is now created from C - D
```

Now, I want to integrate all changes from B to D

What steps do I need to follow for safe merge using Eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in the help (in Eclipse press F1): https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Merging_a_branch_or_a_tag_into_the_current_branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check if all branches are `up-to date`. Otherwise you have to push the branches where are not up-to date.
2. `git checkout D`
3. After checkout command, make `git merge B` in **branch D**
4. Now all changes from **branch B** are in **branch D**

With `git branch` you can see on which branch you are, and which branches are available. With `git branch -a` you list all remote branches.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal, go to project directory and run following:

```
git checkout D
git merge B
```

Comment: Will it create any issue if some files have changes in both branches. There are 42 conflicts

Comment: If there are changes in some files in both branches, there will be conflicts which you need to resolve yourself and then make a commit.

Comment: This solution is how using the Git command line for that, not using Eclipse (which would be easier and faster in this case).